# i want to add layer on map when the function executes

Tags: angular, typescript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

when i call the function of getdate in code i need to add layer on map. But when i directly pass the function in ngoninit() it works fine. but when i call the same function within the getdate function it shows in console. the function executed but is layer not added. In this code below there is reciever of server for data sharing. I want to execute the fucntion in gettimemfromservice in console it show fucntion is executing but layer is not adding on map.

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild, Optional, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, Input } from '@angular/core';
import  * as mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import MapboxGeocoder from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-geocoder';
import MapboxDirections from '@mapbox/mapbox-gl-directions/dist/mapbox-gl-directions';
import { Map } from 'mapbox-gl';
import { ConvertPropertyBindingResult } from '@angular/compiler/src/compiler_util/expression_converter';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { GraphComponent } from '../graph/graph.component';
import { SidebarNavComponent } from '../sidebar-nav/sidebar-nav.component';
import { shareresservice } from '../services/shareres.service';
import {dataservice} from '../services/dataservice';
import { FormGroup, FormBuilder, Validators, FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { gdataresponse } from '../services/gdataresponse.service';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-traficitymap',
  templateUrl: './traficitymap.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./traficitymap.component.css']
})
export class TraficitymapComponent implements OnInit {


  olat:any;
  olng:any;
  dlat:any;
  dlng:any;
  cord:any;
  opoint:any;
  dpoint:any;
  spoint:any;
  directions:any;
  geojson:any;
   startlineid:any;
   endlineid:any;
   myForm: FormGroup;
   submitted = false;
   congestionresponse:any[]=[];
   @ViewChild("traficiytmap",{static:true})  date:any;
   @ViewChild("traficiytmap",{static:true})  time:any;

  // private setgraphdata:any[]=[];
  @ViewChild("traficiytmap",{static:true}) map: Map;
  geocoder:any;
   showcongestion=function()
  {   this.loadgmmavgservice(this.olat,this.olng,this.date,this.time);

  }


  constructor(public fb: FormBuilder,public showgraph:MatDialog,private myService: shareresservice,private congestionapiresp:gdataresponse) { 
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      this.olat=position.coords.latitude;
      this.olng=position.coords.longitude;
      const userCoordinates = [this.olng, this.olat];
      this.cord=userCoordinates;
      this.map.flyTo({
        center: userCoordinates,
        zoom:11
      });
      // lat long of current location
      this.opoint = new mapboxgl.LngLat(this.olng, this.olat);
      console.info(this.opoint);
    });

  // this.showcongestion();
  }



//get date data from shared service.

getdatefromservice()
{
 this.myService.dateobs$.subscribe((date) => {
this.date=date;
    console.log("date from service",date);
}); 


}
gettimefromservice()
{
this.myService.timeobs$.subscribe((time) => {
this.time=time;
   //And he have data here too
    console.log("time from service",time);

    this.loadgmmavgservice(this.olat,this.olng,this.date,this.time);
});

}
//for congestion api response.
loadgmmavgservice(source: string,destination:string,date:string,time:string){
  this.congestionapiresp.getprediction(source,destination,date,time)
  .subscribe(     
  data=>
  { console.log("congestion:",data);
  this.congestionresponse=data;
  //this.map.on('load', this.showlinestring(this.congestionresponse));
  this.showlinestring(this.congestionresponse);


  });
  }

  // on every load of 
  ngOnInit() {

    mapboxgl.accessToken =  '';
     this.map = new mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'map',
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/dark-v10',
      zoom:11,
      });
  //  // remove layer
  //  if (this.map.getLayer('linesource')) this.map.removeLayer('linesource');

      //zoom
      this.showzoomcontrols()
      // current location
      this.showlocation();
    // for poi searching
      this.showpoidata1();
      this.showpoidata2();
       //for service data reciever.
        this.getdatefromservice();
        this.gettimefromservice();
}

// current location function
 showlocation():void{
  this.map.addControl(
    new mapboxgl.GeolocateControl({
    positionOptions: {
    enableHighAccuracy: true
    },
    trackUserLocation: true,
    })
    );
};
//zoom control function
showzoomcontrols()
{
  this.map.addControl(new mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
};
// searching 
showpoidata1()
{
  this.geocoder= new MapboxGeocoder({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
    mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
    countries: 'pk',
    placeholder:'Enter Source...',
    render:true
    });
    document.getElementById('geocoder').appendChild(this.geocoder.onAdd(this.map));
    // coordinates of destination.
    this.geocoder.on('result', (ev) =>{
      var styleSpec = ev.result;
      var ln= styleSpec.geometry.coordinates[0];
      var lt= styleSpec.geometry.coordinates[1];
      this.spoint = new mapboxgl.LngLat(ln, lt);
      console.info(this.spoint);
      this.olng=ln;
      this.olat=lt;
      console.log("source:",this.olng,this.olat);
  });
}
showpoidata2()
{
  this.geocoder= new MapboxGeocoder({
    accessToken: mapboxgl.accessToken,
    mapboxgl: mapboxgl,
    countries: 'pk',
    placeholder:'Enter Destination...',
    render:true
    });
    document.getElementById('geocoder1').appendChild(this.geocoder.onAdd(this.map));
    // coordinates of destination.
    this.geocoder.on('result', (ev)=> {
      var styleSpec = ev.result;
      var ln= styleSpec.geometry.coordinates[0];
      var lt= styleSpec.geometry.coordinates[1];
      this.dpoint = new mapboxgl.LngLat(ln, lt);
      console.info(this.dpoint);
      this.dlng=ln;
      this.dlat=lt;
      console.log("destination",this.dlng,this.dlat);
  });
}

//congestion line with colors
 showlinestring(data:any)
{ 
  var gdata = {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": data
  };

console.log(gdata);


  this.map.on('load', ()=> {

      this.map.addLayer({
        id: "linesource",
        type: "line",
        source: {
          type:"geojson",
          data:gdata
        },

        layout: {
          "line-join": "round",
          "line-cap": "round"
        },
        paint: {
          "line-color": [

            "match",
            ["get", "congestion_level"],
            [ 
              1,

            ],
            "#FA4F05",
            [
              2,

            ],
            "#e02e2e",
            [
              3,

            ],
            "#29EE02",
            "#29EE02"
          ],
          "line-width": 5
        }
      });
        // Geographic coordinates of the LineString
        var coordinates = gdata.features[0].geometry.coordinates;
        var bounds = coordinates.reduce((bounds, coord)=> {
          return bounds.extend(coord);
        }, new mapboxgl.LngLatBounds(coordinates[0], coordinates[0]));

        this.map.fitBounds(bounds,{
          padding: 20
        });
      });

}


}
```

fucntion showing gdata response but adding layer on map.
see the image of response.
[image: Response for function]

Comment: Your questions lacks detail and quality. It is very hard or even impossible to indicate any problem. The code you've posted is not complete and quite bad itself. Consider rewriting a detailed question or rewriting the code.

Comment: @mamichels can you please tell how to add layer after initializing the map

Comment: Didn't you read the comment at all?

Comment: when i run showlinestring() it works fine in ngoninit()

Comment: but when i run the same function in getdatefromservice() it dose not add layer on map.